# Gridview delete button position ? In asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net web application, i am using Gridivew control autogenarate columns is false, auto generate delete button is true. My question is by default delete button is left side, can i move to right side of the gird view? can you help me.

Comment: Is it really necessary to autogenerate it?

Answer (score 0):

`ASP.Net` ultimately renders `HTML` to the browser.

Use `CSS` to manipulate rendered `HTML`.

If necessary, manipulate the `server-side` script to output appropriate `HTML`.